# Dynamic combobox, textbox in a dynamic field using js (ASP.NET)

Tags: dynamic-content

My purpose is to create dynamic textbox and combobox in a dynamic field (this field includes two file upload and a button to add dynamic textbox and combobox). 
Everything works fine, but when I try to remove the dynamic tb and cb, it just works at the first field (and doesn't work at the next field). So please help me to fix it!!!!
And how can I fill data from database to the dynamic combobox???

I have the following codes:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title> 

<script type = "text/javascript">
    var counter = 2;
    function AddFileUpload() {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.setAttribute("id", "FileUploadContainer");
        var nextcounter = counter + 1;

        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        input1.setAttribute("id", "file" + counter);
        input1.setAttribute("name", "file" + counter);
        input1.setAttribute("type", "file");
        div.appendChild(input1);

        var input2 = document.createElement("input");
        input2.setAttribute("id", "file" + nextcounter);
        input2.setAttribute("name", "file" + nextcounter);
        input2.setAttribute("type", "file");
        div.appendChild(input2);

        var button = document.createElement("input");
        button.setAttribute("id", "remove");
        button.setAttribute("type", "button");
        button.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
        button.setAttribute("onclick", "RemoveFileUpload(this)");
        div.appendChild(button);

        var button1 = document.createElement("input");
        button1.setAttribute("id", "add");
        button1.setAttribute("type", "button");
        button1.setAttribute("value", "Add");
        button1.setAttribute("onclick", "AddCombobox(this)");
        div.appendChild(button1);

        document.getElementById("dynamicForm").appendChild(div);
        counter+=2;
    }
    function RemoveFileUpload(obj) {
        document.getElementById("dynamicForm").removeChild(obj.parentNode);
    }
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var cbcounter = 1;
    function AddCombobox(obj) {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.setAttribute("id", "ComboboxContainer");

        var select = document.createElement("select");
        select.setAttribute("name", "sl" + cbcounter);
        select.setAttribute("runat", "server");

        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        var text = document.createTextNode(cbcounter.toString());
        option1.appendChild(text);
        select.appendChild(option1);

        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        text = document.createTextNode((cbcounter + 1).toString());
        option2.appendChild(text);
        select.appendChild(option2);
        div.appendChild(select);

        var textbox = document.createElement("input")
        textbox.setAttribute("name", "txt" + cbcounter);
        textbox.setAttribute("type", "text");
        div.appendChild(textbox);

        var button = document.createElement("input");
        button.setAttribute("id", "removecb");
        button.setAttribute("type", "button");        
        button.setAttribute("onclick", "RemoveCombobox(this)");
        div.appendChild(button);

        obj.parentNode.appendChild(div);
        cbcounter++;
    }
    function RemoveCombobox(obj) {
        document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(obj.parentNode);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "post">

        <span style ="font-family:Arial">Click to add files</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="add field" onclick = "AddFileUpload()" />
        <br /><br />

        <div id = "FileUploadContainer">

            <input id="file0" name = "file0" type="file" runat="server" />            
            <input id="file1" name = "file1" type="file" runat="server" />  
            <input id="addcb" type="button" value="add" onclick = "AddCombobox(this)" />         

            <div id="ComboboxContainer" runat="server"> 
                <select id="sl0" runat="server">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <option value="1"></option>
                </select> 
                <input type="text" name="txt0" value="txt0" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <br />

        <span id="dynamicForm">
        </span>                 

        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm very appreciated for your help!!!